# From plug-in to Eclipse application (or product)

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp, rcp

I have an application what is implemented as eclipse plug-in. It works well as it is expected.

I want to create from this plug-in an eclipse product (with all capabilities of eclipse). Is it possible?

I tried this topic:
http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/EclipseRCP/article.html#plugin_creatinge4

But the result of this process is an empty window. What I want is to all eclipse features + newly developed features to be included into the product. Like an eclipse plug-in, but it is starting as an eclipse product (Splash screen, standalone application etc.).

Can it be solved? If yes, how.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds as if you need to fill in the `.product` file with what you want to ship.

You need to fill in all the dependants in the `Contents` tab of the `.product` file, e.g.:

[image: product contents page]

To make it easier to make a product with the bits you really want, you can use an existing product or launch configuration as the basis of your product. From the `File` -> `New` -> `Other` -> `Plug-in Development` -> `Product Configuration` Wizard, choose either `Use an existing product` or `Use a launch configuration` as the starting point.

Here is an example screenshot showing the options on my install for products to start from:

[image: new product configuration]

Comment: I also recommend trying out this series of blog posts to get your product building at the command line: http://codeandme.blogspot.co.at/p/tycho-articles.html